# Is it possible to create the illusion of a sub-harmonic?

Tags: guitar, theory, harmonics

The way I understand it, a normal plucked tone consists of a great many overtones in addition to the base tone. A pinched harmonic, however, shifts the base tone higher into the overtone series by establishing a *node* in the string's range of vibration, suppressing lower frequencies.

Can you go the other way? I'm imagining some sort of vibrato or tremolo in-phase with one of the missing lower overtones that the desired low tone would have, then you could potentially trick the ear into perceiving the resulting tone as a harmonic of a tone that isn't actually present.

So, is it possible to "play" a subharmonic?

Ps. One other scrap of an idea is to strike the string with a sort of *slap-mute* technique where you impact both the string and the bridge so the vibrating length of string is roughly half the length of the string+body system. Like a deep stroke on a bass drum. It sounds cool, regardless.

Comment: _Neat_ question, but I would suggest retitling it since you already understand that an "actual" subharmonic is impossible. Sounds like you're instead trying to trick the ear into hearing notes below the range of the instrument.

Comment: The idea of using a "tuned" tremolo is interesting. It would be fun to experiment with this.

Comment: @Ulf The tuned-termolo idea came from Paganini's Capriccio #6. *A tempo* the tremolo should be over 24 notes-per-second. Since there's a low A at 22.5hz, a little slower should coincide with a low G (the Key of the piece!) right at the threshold of pitch perception. But I'm still only about half that speed. :(

Comment: @luserdroog Aha. Bummer... :-) I was actually thinking of something more in terms of using a volume tremolo effect pedal that had tremolo frequency adaption based on the pitch played. What further options/ideas could there be?

Comment: This would be an interesting twist on the question... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binaural_beats

Comment: s/22.5hz/27.5Hz/ :)

Comment: [Adam Neely's video on SUBHARMONIC Music (Anomalous Low Frequency Vibration)](https://youtu.be/o4jgPdGrZYI)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As **leftaroundabout** indicated in another answer, you could achieve subharmonics (specifically a *difference* tone) using two sound sources - such as two strings.
See ["Combination tone"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination_tone) on wikipedia for further specifics.
Or see ["Resultant tone"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant_tone) regarding the usage of this for organs, where sometimes two shorter organ pipes are used to sound simultaneously emulating the sound of a longer organ pipe.

I sometimes use this phenomenon on my four-string electric bass: Striking the lowest B (on the A string) and the even lower F# (on the E string) together, creates the illusion of a B one octave lower than the strung B. This makes it sound like if I had a five string electric bass with the low B. When doing this I strike the strings softly about midways up the string to try to feed the fundamentals of the strung notes as much as possible, and to eliminate as many higher partials as possible in order not to give away the mismatching partials of the F#. (In effect it is a powerchord, but I don't use any effect pedal, and I try not to use "power" when playing it. ;-) It also helps to disguise the trick if there are other instruments playing at the same time.

I suppose you could try this on the guitar also.

Comment: The true difference tone in the described case, with a fourth inbetween the played tones, is actually yet an other octave down. The perceived B, closest below the fourth interval, that I refer to, is called the cubic difference tone. See for instance 'Musical Acoustics' by Donald E. Hall, Brooks/Cole Publishing Company, Pacific Grove, CA.

Comment: I'm immensely pleased to read this. .... I'll be in the shed. ... No calls. ... :)

Comment: You'll notice it wont be perfect - it wont sound just as the real thing - but hopefully you can produce a good enough illusion.

Comment: Do you strike them as a *slap* or a *sweep*? You want a little more intensity on the B, less on the F#, right? I can get a *softer overall* attack with a slap, but I can get more *difference of intensity* with a *sweep* pluck. And all with the thumb. ...

Comment: @luserdroog: I _pluck_ them simultaneously using my index and middle fingers. And yes I try to have a little more emphasis on the B. (One day I might post a video, but don't get your hopes up...)

Comment: I just discovered this can be made to work with a *strum* if you apply (palm-)muting (a little more muffling on the lower note, but mute both to keep them in tone).

Comment: Does work well. I do it on guitar when playing power chords. If I create a power chord, say D on the 5th string, and then I add the A below that 5th fret, with some distortion, it appears to sound like a Drop-D power chord.

Comment: @user6164 12 EDO fifths are close enough to just for this.  For difference tones involving major and minor thirds though, you'll need to bend or retune if you want to get the imaginary notes in tune.  Or hire a choir of course.

Comment: Difference tones are readily heard with high instruments such as recorders- this can be exploited, for instance in Hindemith's trio for recorders, where you seem to hear a low F# in a first inversion F# major chord, if it's played well enough in tune.  Listen to the chord at 1:14- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MYzmFyN5nqo

Answer (score 11):

You can't actually do this - obviously you are aware that the whole pich/natural/articial harmonic bit doesn't create frequencies, it just cuts out some so the tonal quality changes.

You do have technological alternatives though, if you do want to build lower frequencies related to the original root.

Octave dividers are the simplest example - you can buy pedals which will give you an output at half or quarter the frequency you play. When mixed with the original signal this can give a nice rich sound, and when attenuated sufficiently, can support the root rather than replacing it.

With modern DSP technology, you can be even cleverer and add in frequencies that are not octaves, or even frequencies unrelated to the original.

Comment: Anyone interested in "unrelated" frequencies shoulld first be brave enough to listen to *Stria*. It's the sound of *The Mountains of Madness*.

Comment: Short of signal processing, I guess the best you could do is some sort of external resonance chamber with "tuned" wolf-tones. Perhaps an arrangement of panels?

Comment: @DrMayhem: You can't do it acoustically using a single tone, but you can do it using two tones. See leftaroundabout and my answers. :-)

Comment: @Ulf - very cool. Must try and play with that idea...

Comment: No disrespect intended by changing acceptance, but the no-tech solution has greater philosophical appeal. :)

Comment: I love the way this one goes "You can't do this, *but*...".

Answer (score 4):

In my answer to [How do harmonics work?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/3849/28), I said:

> [A] vibrating guitar string has components at many multiples of the base frequency (call it **F**).  To your ear it still sounds like the fundamental, but mathematically it's more like this:
>
> > a*F + b*2F + c*3F + ...
>
> The higher-frequency elements give the note it's timbre; this is how you can tell two instruments apart, or even tell different kinds of guitar strings apart.  For example, the sound where `a=1 b=0.6 c=0.3` will sound different than `a=1 b=0.5 c=0.4`.  Note that **a** is always the largest coefficient, since **F** is the fundamental frequency.  If it wasn't it would sound like you were playing a different note, or multiple notes.

That last bit is actually false; I glossed over it for the sake of simplicity.  In fact, it's perfectly possible for the fundamental to be weaker than other components of the sound while the perceived note is still that of the fundamental.

By the same logic, it's also possible for **a** to be so weak that the lowest component is *not* perceived as the fundamental.  In other words, **F** would not be the fundamental, and I think it would be perfectly accurate to call it a "sub-harmonic" in that case.

It might be difficult if not impossible to create such a sound with a single vibrating string (for example), but you could probably do something like play A440 quietly on one string and A880 loudly on another, and end up with the perceived fundamental at A880 with A440 as your sub-harmonic.  Of course, the human ear is quite good and it would also be difficult to prevent the two notes from being perceived distinctly.  This might be easier with electronic approaches, as Dr Mayhem talks about.

Comment: IIRC, the clarinet has a relatively weak fundamental.

Comment: The filtering caused by telephone microphones, speakers, and transmission processing eliminates most low partials. However the human hearing makes up for that and extrapolates the fundamental from the higher partials, and thus a deep voice to still be perceived as deep (but with a phone filter sound). This means you will still "hear" a sung low F as the very low F although the lowest frequency you actually hear might be an octaveor more above.

Comment: This is not true.  Even if a = 0 identically it is still the fundamental of the vibrating system and your brain will fill it in using a process called fundamental tracking.

Answer (score 4):

One possibility is to exploit intermodulation.

One way overtones come up has already been discussed: if you pluck a string, it vibrates in multiple modes from the beginning (explained [here](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/5489/why-do-harmonics-happen/5494#5494)). But there is an important other mechanism: nonlinearities. If you feed a pure overtone-free sine wave through a distortion pedal*, what comes out has a whole bunch of overtones on it, in principle the same ones that also turn up in acoustic instruments: harmonics. (They sure sound quite different, but that has other reasons.)

One might think the same process is going on, standing waves etc., but that's not the case. In fact, not just multiples of the fundamental are created, rather every *difference* between any two frequencies in the input signal is "considered", and you get multiples of it created (I'm not going to prove this here, but it's possible).
*Huh, then why don't we hear a complete mess of thousands of different frequencies when playing a tone that **has** already harmonics with distortion?*
Let's look at it. Suppose the original signal has frequencies
*ν*<sub>*i*</sub>   =   *ν*<sub>0</sub> ⋅ *i*       ∀ *i* ∊ {1,2,3...}

then there are frequency-differences
Δν<sub>*i j*</sub>   =   *ν*<sub>*i*</sub> – *ν*<sub>*j*</sub>
  ∊   { *ν*<sub>0</sub> – *ν*<sub>0</sub> , 2 *ν*<sub>0</sub> – *ν*<sub>0</sub> , ... , *ν*<sub>0</sub> – 2 *ν*<sub>0</sub> , ... }   =   { ... , -2 *ν*<sub>0</sub> , -*ν*<sub>0</sub> , 0 , *ν*<sub>0</sub> , 2 *ν*<sub>0</sub> , 3 *ν*<sub>0</sub> , ... }

These get multiplied and put back on the frequencies in the signal.
*f*<sub>*i j k*</sub>   =   *ν*<sub>*i*</sub> + Δν<sub>*i j*</sub> ⋅ *k*     ∀ *k* ∊ {1,2,3...}

Here you can easily see that the resulting signal will also contain the frequencies { ... , -2 *ν*<sub>0</sub> , -*ν*<sub>0</sub> , 0 , *ν*<sub>0</sub> , 2 *ν*<sub>0</sub> , 3 *ν*<sub>0</sub> , ... }. Negative frequncies? Zero? Well, zero just means no sound, so you can't hear that one. And positive and negative phase velocity is indistinguishable, so effectively we have the frequencies { *ν*<sub>0</sub> , 2 *ν*<sub>0</sub> , 3 *ν*<sub>0</sub> , ... }. **Exactly** the same ones as were in the original tone! Just more powerful, because they are all doubled from the many difference-possibilities. That's why you can put distortion on virtually any *melody*-playing guitar: you get the same frequencies again, so it never sounds wrong (except too loud / unsubtle).

If you play multiple different notes simultaneously, things get a bit more complicated: with a clean sound, the ear can separate them again, and we hear a clear chord. But with distortion, there will be frequency differences that do *not* map again to frequencies originally present in the signal. If it was just a little tube overdrive, these frequencies make up the famous bluesey "dirt" and you can still well distinguish the original chord notes; if you play Jazz chords through a metal distortion pedal the extra frequencies won't be properly seperable and you can't distinguish anything at all anymore. Seldom desirable.

However, you know there is one kind of chord that works at *any* distortion level: exactly, the powerchord. And here's why:
In a perfect fifth, the frequencies have a ratio of 2:3. So if you play a two-stringed<sup>†</sup> powerchord, you have those frequencies in the original signal:
{ *ν*<sub>0</sub> ,  ³⁄₂ *ν*<sub>0</sub> ,  2 *ν*<sub>0</sub> ,  ⁶⁄₂ *ν*<sub>0</sub> ,  3 *ν*<sub>0</sub> ,  ⁹⁄₂ *ν*<sub>0</sub> ,  4 *ν*<sub>0</sub> ,  ... }

where you can find the differences
{ 0 *ν*<sub>0</sub> ,  ½ *ν*<sub>0</sub> ,  1 *ν*<sub>0</sub> ,  2 *ν*<sub>0</sub> ,  2 *ν*<sub>0</sub> ,  ⁷⁄₂ *ν*<sub>0</sub> ,  3 *ν*<sub>0</sub> , ... 
⁻½ *ν*<sub>0</sub> ,  0 *ν*<sub>0</sub> ,  ½ *ν*<sub>0</sub> , ³⁄₂ *ν*<sub>0</sub> , ³⁄₂ *ν*<sub>0</sub> ,  2 *ν*<sub>0</sub> ,  ⁵⁄₂ *ν*<sub>0</sub> , ... 
}
You see what's going on here: *we're getting components with half the original fundamental frequency!* Subharmonics. And those are in fact the reason why powerchords sound so fat.

*It doesn't actually have to be electronic, mechanical distortion work as well. Such are found in the nonlinear air flow in all wind instruments, this effect is used by rock flautist who sing notes while playing, to create intermodulation.
<sup>†</sup>Three-stringed is exactly the same, as the octave only backs up even harmonics of the low string.

Comment: This is exactly the principle of interferences, isn't it?

Comment: Wow. So subharmonic difference tones happen with any chord? Perhaps that's the key to the word "*chord*" itself. A Cord from a Chorus. Perhaps chords work precisely *because* they stand in relation to an imaginary unifying pitch. Like watching a scaly lizard from above. You can only see a pattern of flashing shapes as the scales change their angle to the sun. But the pattern of movement is truly governed by the feet.

Comment: @luserdroog: "subharmonic difference tones happen with any chord" well, in a sense yes; but for chords played on "clean" instruments such as piano, acoustic guitar or an ensemble of melody instruments, the difference tones are just amplitude envelopes, which can _not_ directly be perceived. Only when you apply distortion, they become actual sound vibrations. — Interesting analogy with the lizards, that's the poet's way of looking at it. Of course you can as well explain chords quite boringly by the fact that various harmonics of different strings fall on the same frequencies.

Comment: I wonder if *buzzing* the strings against the frets could produce the desired distortion on a "clean" guitar...

Comment: @luserdroog: string buzzing is indeed comparable to distortion in a way, but as it happens _separately_ for each string it does not cause any intermodulation.

Comment: The difference tone creates the envelope modulation but is not a true frequency of the the system.  If you were to use a mic+DAC system and an FFT you will NOT find the difference tone.  Interference is a linear phenomenon and that does not create sub harmonics.

Answer (score 4):

The first subharmonic, an octave below, can be produced on the violin by applying the right amount of bowing pressure (more than usual) and also bowing slowly, if I recall this correctly. As far as I know, this technique requires lots of practice to master. Similarly, subharmonics can be produced by the voice if tensing the vocal cords, as you can try for yourself.

In some synthesis techniques, in particular when using nonlinearities and feedback, you get a whole cascade of subharmonics that usually end up with chaos. This is an inherent property of the system, and probably there are some underlying similarities with the way subharmonics are produced in acoustic instruments.

Comment: That's awesome! Found a link with more: http://www.marikimura.com/subharmonics.html

Comment: Yes! Mari Kimura is amazing and can produce more than just the 8ve-lower subharmonic. I know she can do the 8ve+5th sub, and I think maybe even more. @luserdroog

Answer (score 2):

In a sense, you actually can. Go to 0:06 in this video and you'll see the technique used.

You'll need distortion, but basically what you do, is you play one natural harmonic on one string, and then another natural harmonic on a different string, but on the second string, you fret the note instead of lift your finger off right after you get the harmonic right. from there, bend your fretted finger and with distortion, you should hear a low sound that sounds a lot like a sub drop. Using these I can "play" certain notes lower than my 7-string in Drop A.

I don't know if that answered your question, but I think that's as close as you're going to get with just a guitar, a pick, distortion, and a speaker that can sound bass frequencies.

Answer (score 2):

I've only ever seen Michael League (bassist from Snarky Puppy) talk about this, but you can get an OC2 effect by picking directly on the octave harmonic.

You can see him do this in his Reverb interview on bass-pedals.

3:38 is where he explains what he does. I have no clue what this is called.

Answer (score 1):

i can produce subharmonics with a classical guitar tuned down a bit.
i have the 6th string E tuned to C#.  the 5th A down to G# and the 4th string D down to C#.  Fret the 12th fret on the 6th string and the 12th fret on the 4th string leaving the 5th string open.  When all three strings are plucked lightly you can clearly hear a low D# which normally can only be produced at the 2nd fret of the 6th string.
There are similar "ghost tones" found all over the guitar but this is one
of the most prominent to the ear on my guitar.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. At least, you can make people hear a note lower, even if you don't actually make it. To start, tune a guitar to Drop-D. (You needn't always use this tuning, but it's the easiest to demonstrate with.) This makes the lowest two strings D2 and A2.

On only the lowest two strings, fret the 5th fret on the D string (G2) and the third on the A string (C3), palm-mute, and strum--you'll hear a C2. Because the G2 is the 5th of, and C3 is the full octave (8th) of, C2, your mind fills in the missing fundamental (C2). (4th and 2nd fret for B1, 3rd and open for A1). Note, you're not actually producing this note, it's just an auditory hallucination that most (not all) people will hear. Some folks will simply not hear anythin more than a G2 and a C3.

This works best when palm-muting to reduce the higher harmonics of the notes you're actually playing, but can be done easily on an acoustic.

Comment: Hi, senselock. Welcome to the site! The information in your answer is very similar to the accepted answer. But you describe it in a very different way so I don't see any particular problem with it. Note in 12TET, you may wish to bend 5th up a smidge to get a Just interval.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a multi faceted question with quite a bit of depth to it.  I will add something to this but my answer will also be multi-faceted.  I am not going to consider electronic enhancements.  And I will pose some additional questions to you.

First: If you are asking about exciting a tone lower than the lowest natural frequency of the instrument but resonance AND the instrument is linear (obeys the physics of linear response) then I'd say no.  Linear systems typically do not behave that way.

Second: It has been observed that sub-harmonics can be excited in horns with just the right kind of "blow" (for lack of a better term) in terms of force and direction.  Similar statements have been made of stringed instruments.

This does not contradict the previous statement as we probably think of the lowest pitch string as defining the lowest vibrational frequency of the guitar as a system and this is not quite accurate.  The basic model of string harmonics taught in elementary physics texts treat the string a being fixed at both ends.  This is not how strings really work.  On an acoustic guitar the bridge and top movement will change this model.  So in theory it s possible to excite a longer wavelength in the instrument.  The excitation is related to the driving force, whether bowed, blown, plucked or struck.

Third: In non-linear systems sub-harmioncs are more commonplace.  Some musical instruments may contain such non-linearities (it is our tendency to simplify the system so we can understand it based on what we can solve and thus it may be that no instrument is truly linear, but can be expected to be approximately linear).  We live with this approximation and forget the more complex reality, convincing ourselves that it cannot be done.

Fourth: There is a phenomenon called fundamental tracking that I believe is purely neurological, a brain function.  If the brain is presented with a sequence of tones that obey the standard harmonic sequence it will fill in the gap, calculating and inserting the mathematical fundamental.  This is a very interesting part of the human system. The ear is non-linear and when excited creates aural harmonics.  As a result of this it is not likely that we can hear a "pure tone" generates by a function generator hooked up to a speaker.  These two phenomenon have far reaching consequences w/r to our perception of tone.

As for actual guitar technique, I don't know of any for the acoustic.  Some folks have offered possibilities but I haven't actually tried any.  On purely theoretical grounds if you were to create a chord sequence that contained an implicit fundamental below the notes I suspect a person would hear that lower note, but this is not the same as generating it acoustically.  Comparison of a spectral analysis of the sound and the claim made by the listener would differ.